# Uncovering Mysterious CustomCommand Functionality

Tags: c#, add-in, enterprise-architect

Here's my question, how does one "hack" the CustomCommand in Enterprise Architect's API to figure out what it's capabilities are? Here's what I'm currently using it for, which seems to be an accepted (by the community) and usable function:

```
repository.CustomCommand("Repository", "ImportRefData", xml);
```

I want to see what else I can do with it, namely some exporting of said reference data.

Also, while Sparx cannot officially support this functionality since it's undocumented, what are the odds that this command will stay functional with updated versions of EA, do they have a history of breaking illegal code like this?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: you can't. The few commands I documented were from postings on the Sparx forum. Eventually they originated from Sparx support itself. I remember having read from someone who knew about one of the commands asking for more info. But Sparx did not unveil more than was known. I tried to find the strings in the EXE but to no avail.

Since the function is there for quite some years and Sparx is very reluctant to substantial changes in the API it will likely not change. So it's save to use the function in future. IIRC Sparx itself recommended the use in certain cases. But only on the forum...

Comment: I forgot: see repository.GetReferenceList (string Type) in the help.